# Installed ruby 2.1.1, rails is using 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run my first rails app and I have specified ruby 2.1.1 in my Gemfile, but when I try to run bundle install I get the following meessage:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1.
```

When I run `rvm current`, I get 2.1.1 as the current ruby install. However, when I enter ruby -v, I get 1.9.3. How do I get rails to recognize 2.1.1 as the current version? Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm very new to this and I'd like to get started on my first app! Thanks for your help. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which version of ruby you want to use via:

`rvm use 2.1.1 do bundle install`

but I would advice you create `.rvmrc` file or a `.ruby-version` file

sample `.rvmvrc` would contain

```
rvm use 2.1.1
```

sample `.ruby-version` would contain

```
2.1.1
```

with a `.ruby-version` or `.rvmrc` whenever you `cd` into your project `rvm` would automatically change your ruby version to the desired one

Comment: isn't `.rvmvrc` deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Some useful commands:

- use `rvm install 2.1.1` if you want to install `ruby 2.1.1`
- set default with `rvm --default use 2.1.1` if you want to use latest ruby
- or you can switch back to different ruby version e.g. 2.0.0 with `rvm use 2.0.0`